# Linq Query Crash if Return Null

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I run this query And if The Query is return with empty values the programme is crashed.

```
var cust = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.telephone == txtTel.Text);
if (cust.BlackList == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This customer is blacklisted, Do you wish to continue with this job?"); 
}
```

Please Suggest me Some Efficient solution
Thanks.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if `FirstOrDefault()` returns null, i.e. there's no such record?

Comment: @jon skeet it shouldnt show any message

Comment: But are you going to use `cust` later in the method? Perhaps you want to return immediately? Do you understand that `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` (for reference types) if it can't find any matches? (If you do, it's not clear why you don't know what to do if it returns null...)

Comment: @JonSkeet if cust  is return Null it means Customer is not black list and it is ok for further operation.the problem is when it return a Value.

Comment: No, that's not what it means at all. It means the customer hasn't been found. The predicate you've used in `FirstOrDefault` doesn't have anything to do with blacklisting - it *only* checks the telephone number.

Comment: telephone number requires to fetch the record from table and after that I check is this record is black list or not.
Jon skeet If you see any wrong approach in above code  have any thing please tell .

Comment: It's not so much a wrong approach, as that you don't understand what your code is doing. If `cust` is `null`, that means the query returned no results. You need to work out what you want to do in that situation, and avoid checking if "the customer" is blacklisted in that case, because there *is* no customer to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer because FirstOrDefault returns the default value of the object if the result is not found (in this case it is null):

```
var cust = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.telephone == txtTel.Text);
if (cust != null && cust.BlackList == 1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("This customer is blacklisted, Do you wish to continue with this job?");   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `null` because that's what `FirstOrDefault` returns if there is no record that satisfies your condition:

```
if(cust != null && cust.BlackList == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault will return a default value if there is no element in the list which satisfy the condition, in this case it will be null. As you call a property on the null value it will naturally cause an exception.

You should check if cust is null, like:

```
if(cust != null && cust.BlackList == 1)
```

Of course you can display another message if the user doesn't exist based on the logic of your application.